# OpenCV create_samples fails

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have 567 positive images which are referenced in my `positives.txt` file using the following format(assume each image only has 1 object):

```
path num_of_objects x1 y1 x2 y2
```

When I run

```
opencv_createsamples -info ../data/positives.txt -num 567 -w 256 -h 256 -vec training.vec
```

I receive the following error

```
Unable to open image: ../data//Users/jkarimi91/Documents/Projects/kaggle/right_whale_recognition/data/imgs/train/whale_00195/w_2753.jpg
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -9 () in cvSetImageROI, file /Users/jhelmus/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 3000
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/jhelmus/anaconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.8/modules/core/src/array.cpp:3000: error: (-9)  in function cvSetImageROI

Abort trap: 6
```

what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had improperly formatted the txt file; it should be formatted as follows (assume that each image only contains 1 object):

`path num_of_objects x y width height`